# sql comparing dates wrongly

Tags: php, date, sql-view

```
<?php         
     date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
     $currentDate =  date("d M Y h:i:s a");
     $sql=mysql_query("update products set past=0 where valid_date>'".$currentDate."'");
     $sql1=mysql_query("update products set past=1 where valid_date<'".$currentDate."'");
?>
```

---

The above is my  code. if `valid_date` is 31 Jan 2017 12:25:07 pm the SQL query still takes this as future date(i.e greater than today's date) but it takes 05 Feb 2017 12:25:07 pm as past. Precisely to say that the query is comparing February dates correctly and January dates wrongly.

what is wrong in my code?

Comment: You should check MySql Date operations https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php         
     date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
     $sql=mysql_query("update products set past = CASE WHEN valid_date > NOW() THEN 0 WHEN valide_date < NOW() THEN 1 END where 1 = 1");
?>
```

This is documentation for [NOW()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) mysql function.

And as your condition states, this code will work.

Comment: i tried running this code. The past remains 0  for all.There is no change

Comment: try running this query in mysql browser. and check if updating, and what is date format of column in your table

Comment: Now i tried running the query in mysql browser,it turned all past to 1 and the date format of column in my table is varchar

Comment: OHH .... and what is sample date format ? Why you kept it varchar if its date field ?

Comment: ive given input type as text in html(since its easy to retrieve) so i have kept it as varchar.

Comment: i changed the format to datetime.Now its working correctly.Thank you @rahul_m